# How can I define variable in javascript using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, geojson

I am developing an application and I would like to define a javascript variable using PHP code.  In a database I have in 3 points from the type batiment and I would that the variable `geojson` point had 3 value (I would that the variable `var geojson_Point` have all the result of the request in the geometry `"geometry" : echo $rslt;")`.

```
var geojson_Point = 
{
    <?php 
    $query = "SELECT ST_ASGeoJSON(geometry) FROM poi where type='batiment'";  
    $result = pg_query($con, $query);
    while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))  
    {  
        foreach($row as $rslt);
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": { },
            "geometry":
        echo $rslt; 
    } 
    ?>;
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: i have in database 3 point from the type batiment and i whould that the variable geojson point had 3 value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define `javascript` variable from `PHP` use :

```
var JS_variable = <?php echo $PHP_variable; ?>;
```

In your case a suggest to separate **php** & **javascript** codes like following :

**PHP :**

```
$result_array = array();

while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))  
{  
    foreach($row as $rslt){
        $geojson_point = array("type" => "Feature", "properties" => "{}", "geometry" => $rslt);

        array_push($result_array, $geojson_point);
    }
}
```

Pass the variable to javascript like following :

**JS :**

```
var geojson_point = <?php echo json_encode($result_array); ?>;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but in geojson format you should have this "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
   },
   "geometry":

Comment: That called an **[Object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)** in javascript.

Comment: yes but in the code php can learn this this "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": in the bocle while

Comment: What is the final result that you desired ?

Comment: i whould that the variable "var geojson_Point" have all the result of th requete in the geometry ""geometry":
        echo $rslt;"

Comment: i whould that the variable "var geojson_Point" have all the result of th requete in the geometry ""geometry": echo $rslt;

Comment: yes he can do this but but my variable is in javascript not in php "geojson point"  not "$geojson_point" i would that be var geojson_point??

Comment: Pass variable from php to js using `var geojson_point = <?php echo $result_array; ?>;` .

Comment: yes zakaria but in my variable js as you view i have i bocle while and another expression like ""type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry"" can you modifie the code that can i use it please!!!

Comment: No, not more your variable now is `var geojson_point = <?php echo $result_array; ?>;` I separate the php code and js code, please read the answer slowly.

Comment: but zakaria he say that in the final resultat : var geojson_point = <?php echo $result_array; ?>; "Notice: Array to string conversion"

Comment: yes he can show the result but like this ({\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-5.389654,34.896542]}"}) but i would that the result be like this ({"type":"Point","coordinates":[-5.389654,34.896542]})

Comment: i would not this \\\??

Comment: How you show the variable in your js ? alert or console.log or ..?

Comment: i don't understand you but i would a format like the geojson format like this like this ({"type":"Point","coordinates":[-5.389654,34.896542]}) not this ({\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-5.389654,34.896542]}"}) are you undertand me i would not show this \\\ in the result?? please help me!

Comment: yes i do the console to view the format of the result after the use it in the code :/

Comment: are you understand me @zakaria :/

Comment: Yes, try for example to replace the `"` by empty using `your_result_varibale.replace(/\\/g,'');`

Comment: If `console.log(geojson_point);` show the `\"` try `console.log(geojson_point.replace(/\\/g,''));`.